# why is the body always empty on my facebook messenger bot posts?

Tags: facebook, webhooks, messenger

I have set up my messenger bot webhooks correctly.  posts to it work great with postman.  but when I send a message to the page through messenger - it only does a get.  the get challenge is accepted, but the body is empty and there is never a post .
So when I send a fb message to the page "Jacksonville Beach Condos" the body always comes back empty. But, if you use postman or curl - curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "dreamrealty.com:8000/webhook" -d '{"object": "page", "entry": [{"messaging": [{"message": "TEST_MESSAGE"}]}]}' IT WORKS PERFECTLY. So I don't understand why the fb message just does a GET for the challenge, but doesn't POST the message after the challenge succeeded. –  Any help will be highly appreciated as I am totally stumped.

I've tried to resubscribe with curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=EAAH4I6ZBuQtkBAJCy3x7bTsgxfmFa5xP9USaEpp9h08dxCuJO9YmiFZAZC32OpAMUWkZBWNrXwlZBg12oHrtfZA25rXMBvoPKSZCeitznn9KQopYHpf6niVxCYlBvMvkA0ia1wCAg2oAOCZA5eYGfOtBLgulp1IqT6qdCZCrZCSXoWYQZDZD  - but I get {"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires manage_pages permission to manage the object","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"F0ODse5knLk"}}  - I don't see anywhere to manage_pages permission without going through app review - but my app is not ready for review.  Very frustrating....

Comment: you need to include a lot more details, and the relevant code.

Comment: you need to edit your question. add all relevant information in the question, NEVER in comments.

Comment: thank you - question edited

Comment: Accepting the challenge is a one-time thing that happens when you set up your webhook URL. If you are getting this over and over again(?), then that step didn’t perform correctly so far.